# seaborn in jupyter notebook: why does sns.despine() work for lmplot but not regplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

Jupyter notebook, using Python 3:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
sns.despine()
```

then

```
snstest1 = sns.regplot(x="foo", y="bar", data=my_data)
```

shows a plot with the unwanted border box (i.e., sns.despine() doesn't seem to have affected it).

but:

```
snstest2 = sns.lmplot(x="foo", y="bar", data=my_data)
```

shows a plot with the unwanted border box correctly removed.

The only documentation I can find that seems to bear directly on this is the following, from [the api docs for regplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html):

> Understanding the difference between regplot() and lmplot() can be a
>   bit tricky. In fact, they are closely related, as lmplot() uses
>   regplot() internally and takes most of its parameters. However,
>   regplot() is an axes-level function, so it draws directly onto an axes
>   (either the currently active axes or the one provided by the ax
>   parameter), while lmplot() is a figure-level function and creates its
>   own figure, which is managed through a FacetGrid. This has a few
>   consequences, namely that regplot() can happily coexist in a figure
>   with other kinds of plots and will follow the global matplotlib color
>   cycle. In contrast, lmplot() needs to occupy an entire figure, and the
>   size and color cycle are controlled through function parameters,
>   ignoring the global defaults.

But I don't fully understand the difference between a "figure" and an "axis."  The best guess I can make without knowing the underlying model here is that when these weird global-state-mutating functions built into Seaborn, like `despine` and (?) `set_palette` and such, are active, only "figures," not "axes," check that state before rendering?  But if that's so, how would I get something that generates an "axis" to plot in accordance with what I've requested?

Comment: Maybe not a dupe but this question helps explain the different between figures and axes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47065244/do-i-need-a-figure-what-are-they-for/47065412#47065412

Comment: that is helpful.  I think what I really want is to learn the underlying object-oriented interface rather than screw around with all these leaky abstractions on top of it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: Call `sns.despine` **after** your plotting function.

The longer version:

`lmplot` creates its own figure. But it does not need despine. It will do it automatically, even without calling `sns.despine`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)

plt.show()
```

[image]

This is the reason the code from the question actually seems to work.
However, what is really happening is that if you call `sns.despine` before any figure is created, it will act on a newly created figure. The code from the question is hence creating two figures. One, which is empty, but also is "despined" and then one which is the `lmplot` figure and which is "despined" because every `lmplot` is despined by default.

A `regplot` is instead created in an axes of a matplotlib figure. If no figure or axes is provided, it will create a new one. This means that `sns.despine` needs to know which axes to despine. If you call it before anything else, there will again be two figures: One, which is empty, but also is "despined" and then one which is the `regplot` figure. This figures axes are not "despined", because noone told them so.

So the idea is of course to call `sns.despine` **after** creating the plot. You may specify which figure or axes to despine as argument (`sns.despine(ax=ax)`)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.regplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
sns.despine(ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

but if you only have a single subplot that wouldn't even be necessary. Hence

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.regplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
sns.despine()
```

will work equally well and produce

[image]